# jQuery autocomplete or filter instead of a really long <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have a page where you can choose from one of 350 people.

There is limited space to make this selection so there is a select menu with 350 options in it, each with a person's name.

When the page is submitted, the id (selected ption value=X) is submitted and recorded.

It works functionally but it's not ideal having to scroll such a long list.

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin, or similar I can use, perhaps some sort of autocomplete type thing which would do the job in a more user-friendly and sexy way? :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try jquery autocomplete combobox.

see demo here. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has a built-in plugin called Autocomplete, which sounds like precisely what you're looking for: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/